# Having problems with Ionic/Angular ngFor through an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am having some problems with ngFor and cannot find my solution from other questions, if anyone could offer some advice that would be extremely helpful.

My current code is this:

```
 <ion-list *ngIf="items.length">
 <ion-item-sliding style="background-color: #ff2d85" #item>
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
 <ion-avatar item-start><img src="../../assets/imgs/{{item.prodAvatar}}">
 </ion-avatar>
 <h2 id=prod{{i}}Title>{{item.prodTitle}}</h2>
 <h3 id=prod{{i}}Desc>{{item.prodDesc}}</h3>
 <p id=prod{{i}}Little>{{item.prodLittle}}</p>
 <button id="bt{{i}}" ion-button outline item-end class="listbutton" 
 (click)="cart([i])"><ion-icon name="basket"></ion-icon></button>
 </ion-item>
 <ion-item-options side="right">
 <button ion-button expandable></button>
 </ion-item-options>
 </ion-item-sliding>
 <ion-item>
  <button ion-button>NEW PAGE</button>
  <button ion-button secondary menuToggle>MENU</button>
  <button (click)="openVibrate()" ion-button>VIBRATE</button>
  <button (click)="openCamera()" ion-button>CAMERA</button>
 </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

This displays my data fine, except for the problem that the slider on the list only slides on the first object in this list, which is obvious as the sliding element is outside of the for loop. But, when I place the ngFor in the `<ion-item-sliding>`, all data using `{{i}}`, still remains, but the data using `{{item.anything}}` is now blank.

The solution may be clear as day, but I cannot see what it is

Can anybody offer any insight?

Comment: you have to close the ion-item of the for loop before closing ion-item-sliding

Comment: Please can you ellaboarate? I close the <ion-item> before the sliding item, check here: `(click)="cart([i])"><ion-icon name="basket"></ion-icon></button>
 </ion-item>
 <ion-item-options side="right">
 <button ion-button expandable></button>
 </ion-item-options>
 </ion-item-sliding>`

Comment: Please check the opening and closing of tags. some tags are not closed properly. check the closing of this tag <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">

Comment: @PrithiviRaj Thanks for the response, but after checking all of my tags I cannot find one that is missing a closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ngFor` in `ion-item-sliding` tag.

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" style="background-color: #ff2d85" #item1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I put the `ngFor` in the `ion-item-sliding` tag, I lose all of my data.

For clarity, I will upload pictures momentarily.

Comment: [This is what my data looks like when the ngFor is in the <ion-item> tag](https://i.imgur.com/gKKPNJW.png), but, 

[This is what my data looks like when the ngFor is in the <ion-item-sliding> tag](https://i.imgur.com/X1URyRb.png)

These are the only things I am changing.

Comment: please rename `#item` for example to `#item1`